# if $f$ is injective, then is it right $f(B^c) =f(B)^c$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$, and $A$ is subset of $X$.

Then is it right $f(A^c) = f(A)^c$ if $f$ is injective?

What about the condition "injective" is not involved?

Comment: You can't even evaluate $f(B)$ since $B$ is not in the domain. Perhaps you mean $f^{-1}$, or $B \subseteq X$? For $f^{-1}$, this is true regardless whether $f$ is injective or not, but for $f$ with $B \subseteq X$, you indeed need injectivity.

Comment: How do we know if $B$ is contained in $X$ so that $f$ can operate on it?

Comment: oh sorry. I fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, $B$ should be a subset of X, not of Y.
Yes, injectivity is required but also surjectivity  is required for the equality to hold.
With injectivity we only have, $ f(B^c) \subset (f(B))^c$
A counterexample would be

$f(x) = tan^{-1}x$

Since taking   $ B = \mathbb{R}\setminus{0}  $

we have,
$f(B^c) = f(0) = 0$

But, $ (f(B))^c = [π/2, \infty) \cup (-\infty, -π/2] \cup {0}$

Comment: You mean subset, not element, I think.

Comment: thank you for the answer

Comment: @saulspatz - Thank you for pointing that out@cokecokecoke - You're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Why is injectivity needed? Consider $f: \{1, 2\} \to \{0\}$, with $f(1) = f(2) = 0$, and $A = \{1\}$. $f(A) = \{0\}$ and $f(A^c) = \{0\}$ as well.

Why is injectivity sufficient? Say $x \in f(A^c)$, then there is $w \in A^c$ such that $f(w) = x$. But $f$ is injective. So no other thing $w' \in X$ will have $f(w') = x$. In particular, for any $w' \in A$, $w' \not= w$, and thus $f(w') \not= x$. This means $x \not\in f(A)$ and thus $x \in f(A)^c$. Since $x$ is chosen arbitrary,  this shows that $f(A^c) \subseteq f(A)^c$.

The other direction is similar.